# NASM-64bits-segmentation fault calling procedure

Tags: assembly, nasm

When i run  the program i have a segmentation fault. The program consists a simple add between two numbers, store the value in a variable and later print it making a syscall.

Here is the code where i call it:

```
section .bss
    res: resq 1
    fout: resq 1

section .data
     msg dq 'Hello, world!', 0xa  ;string to be printed
     len equ $ - msg     ;length of the string 
     filename dq 'hello.txt'

section .text
     global _start:     ;must be declared for linker (ld)

_start:             ;tells linker entry point
     mov rcx,5
     mov rdx,4
     call sum
     mov [res],rax

     mov    rdx,1     ;message length
     mov    rcx,res  ;message to write
     mov    rbx,1       ;file descriptor (stdout)
     mov    rax,4       ;system call number (sys_write)
     syscall        ;call kernel

     mov    rax,1       ;system call number (sys_exit)
     syscall       ;call kernel

 sum:
     mov rax,rcx
     add rax,rdx
     add rax,'0'
     ret
```

Debug info:

```
 (gdb) n
 sum () at Hello.asm:41
 41              mov rax,rcx
 (gdb) n
 42              add rax,rdx
 (gdb) n
 43              add rax,'0'
(gdb) n
 sum () at Hello.asm:44
 44              ret
 (gdb) n
 0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
 (gdb) n
 No se pueden encontrar límites en la función actual
 (gdb) quit
```

The result is a segmentation fault.

Comment: What happens after `call sum` in “the code where i call it?” The debugger indicates that the code crashed there.

Comment: I store the value and i make a syscall for print the result.

Comment: Please post that code.  Best would you if you posted the whole program or any other form of [mcve] so others can understand what the problem is by running your code on their own computers.

Comment: I put the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to store 8 bytes in `res` with `mov [res],rax` despite only 1 byte being allotted to `res`.  While this is wrong, this is not the problem that causes your program to fail. Write `mov [res], al` to fix this.

The real problem is that your system call numbers are wrong.  You use the system call numbers for i386 Linux, but these are amd64 system calls which have different numbers.  Refer to the values in `asm/unistd_64.h` for the correct system call numbers.  For your example, the correct numbers are `1` for `sys_write` and `60` for `sys_exit`.  Fixing these numbers makes your program no longer crash, but it still doesn't work correctly.

You also need to fix the registers used.  The calling convention for system calls on amd64 is not the same as for i386; you don't put the arguments in ebx, ecx, etc.  Instead, you use `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`, `r10`, `r8`, and `r9` as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2538212/417501).  Fixing this makes your program finally work.

Comment: Its works!, thanks!, one question what is better programing assembly in 32 or 64bits?

Comment: @Roca For serious development, 64 bit assembly is the future as 32 bit is going nowhere.  For learning, 32 bit assembly might be easier due to the simpler calling convention.

Comment: Last question @fuz, do you know any page for learning nasm 64 bits with exercises?

Comment: @Roca Sadly not.